# connect two tables in latex with arrow and make 2 columns more symmetric

Tags: tables, beamer, positioning, arrows

I would like to make the following slide in beamer. However, I find difficulties in making more symmetric the two tables by using `multicols` package. My other question depends on the arrow connecting the smaller red table with the first line (in this slide) of the 2nd table.[image]

My code is:

```
\documentclass[xcolor={dvipsnames,svgnames}]{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usecolortheme{spruce}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage{ucs} 
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{kerkis}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{booktabs,dcolumn}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\usetikzlibrary{matrix,shapes,arrows,fit,tikzmark}
\newcolumntype{.}{D{.}{.}{-1}}
\begin{document}
% Some options common to all the nodes and paths
\tikzset{   
        every picture/.style={remember picture,baseline},
        every node/.style={anchor=base,align=center,outer sep=1.5pt},
        every path/.style={thick},
        }

\newcommand\marktopleft[1]{%
    \tikz[overlay,remember picture] 
        \node (marker-#1-a) at (.1em,.3em) {};%
}
\newcommand\markbottomright[1]{%
    \tikz[overlay,remember picture] 
        \node (marker-#1-b) at (.1em,.3em) {};%
    \tikz[overlay,remember picture,inner sep=3pt]
        \node[draw=red,rounded corners,fit=(marker-#1-a.north west) (marker-#1-b.south east)] {};%
}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{A' Επιλογή}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
    \toprule
    Παραγωγικοί & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Κατανομή Π.Σ.} \\ 
Συντελεστές & Αγαθό $x$ & Αγαθό $y$ \\
\midrule
    Εργασία & \marktopleft{b1}0     & 20 \\
    Έδαφος & 0     & 10 \\
    Κεφάλαιο & 0     & 8\markbottomright{b1} \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%

\begin{tabular}{rrr}
    \toprule
          & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\small Παραγόμενες Ποσότητες} \\
          & $x$     & $y$ \\
\midrule
    Α     & 0     & 600 \\
\\
\\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%


\end{multicols}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: BTW: can you check your previous questions for answers to accept? Many of them have answers which seem to answer the questions.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1):

To gain control over the spacing, you can use the `\columns` environment provides by beamer:

```
\documentclass[xcolor={dvipsnames,svgnames}]{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usecolortheme{spruce}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage{ucs} 
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
%\usepackage{kerkis}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{booktabs,dcolumn}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\usetikzlibrary{matrix,shapes,arrows,fit,tikzmark}
\newcolumntype{.}{D{.}{.}{-1}}
\begin{document}
    % Some options common to all the nodes and paths
    \tikzset{   
        every picture/.style={remember picture,baseline},
        every node/.style={anchor=base,align=center,outer sep=1.5pt},
        every path/.style={thick},
    }

    \newcommand\marktopleft[1]{%
        \tikz[overlay,remember picture] 
        \node (marker-#1-a) at (.1em,.3em) {};%
    }
    \newcommand\markbottomright[1]{%
        \tikz[overlay,remember picture] 
        \node (marker-#1-b) at (.1em,.3em) {};%
        \tikz[overlay,remember picture,inner sep=3pt]
        \node[draw=red,rounded corners,fit=(marker-#1-a.north west) (marker-#1-b.south east)] {};%
    }
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{A' Επιλογή}
        \begin{columns}[onlytextwidth]
            \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
            \begin{tabular}{ccc}
                \toprule
                Παραγωγικοί & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Κατανομή Π.Σ.} \\ 
                Συντελεστές & Αγαθό $x$ & Αγαθό $y$ \\
                \midrule
                Εργασία & \marktopleft{b1}0     & 20 \\
                Έδαφος & 0     & 10 \\
                Κεφάλαιο & 0     & 8\markbottomright{b1} \\
                \bottomrule
            \end{tabular}%
            \end{column}
            \begin{column}{.42\textwidth}
            \hfill
            \begin{tabular}{rrr}
                \toprule
                & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\small Παραγόμενες Ποσότητες} \\
                & $x$     & $y$ \\
                \midrule
                Α     & 0     & 600 \\
                \\
                \\
                \bottomrule
            \end{tabular}%
            \end{column}            
        \end{columns}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: And what about the arrow connecting the middle of the red box with the first line of the 2nd table?

Comment: You can add the arrow the same way, you added the red box.