# An issue with hf-tikz and xcolor

Tags: tables, beamer, color, hf-tikz

It seems that `\rowscolors` (of `xcolor`) and `\tikzmarkin` (of `hf-tikz`) are not compatible. Here is a minimal example to illustrate the issue:

```
\documentclass[xcolor={table,dvipsnames}]{beamer}
\usepackage[customcolors,beamer]{hf-tikz}

\usetheme{Copenhagen}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{}

\begin{table}
\centering 
\rowcolors{2}{gray!20}{white}
\begin{tabular}{lccc}
A & B & C & D \\ 
00 & 100\% & 100\% & 0\% \\ 
\tikzmarkin<1>{a} 05  &  58 & 181  & 50 \tikzmarkend{a} \\ 
\tikzmarkin<2>{b} 10 & 87 & 112 & 1.6 \tikzmarkend{b} \\ 
20 & 92 & 115 & 1.6 \\ 
30 & 87 & 117 & 1.6 \\ 
40 & 81 & 121 & 1.6 \\ 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}%

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Please note that the annotation created by `hf-tikz` is only showing above the first cell of the row, whereas it should cover the complete row. The following figure shows the output of the example above:

[image]

Also, it seems that the first cell of the the row is no longer left-justified as should be. Any hint on how to fix this, please?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Regarding left-justification: Observe that also the last column is no longer properly justified. This justification problem is due to bugs in the commands `\tikzmarkin` and `\tikzmarkend`: quite a lot of `%` signs are missing in their definition. Regarding the interference with `\rowcolors`: I'm afraid that this is an incompatibility that cannot be easily resolved, so you have to decide either for `hf-tikz` of for `\rowcolors` from the `xcolor` package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a workaround, don't use `hf-tikz`, but do the highlighting yourself:

```
\documentclass[xcolor={table,dvipsnames}]{beamer}

\usetheme{Copenhagen}

% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/315248/36296
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,shapes,arrows,fit,tikzmark}

% Some options common to all the nodes and paths
\tikzset{   
    every picture/.style={remember picture,baseline},
    every node/.style={anchor=base,align=center,outer sep=1.5pt},
    every path/.style={thick},
}

\newcommand\marktopleft[1]{%
    \tikz[overlay,remember picture] 
    \node (marker-#1-a) at (.1em,.3em) {};%
}
\newcommand\markbottomright[1]{%
    \tikz[overlay,remember picture] 
    \node (marker-#1-b) at (.1em,.3em) {};%
    \tikz[overlay,remember picture,inner sep=1pt]
    \node[draw=red,rounded corners,fit=(marker-#1-a.north west) (marker-#1-b.south east)] {};%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{}

\begin{table}
\centering 
\rowcolors{2}{gray!20}{white}
\begin{tabular}{lccc}
A & B & C & D \\ 
00 & 100\% & 100\% & 0\% \\ 
\only<1>{\marktopleft{a}}05 & 58 & 181 & 50\only<1>{\markbottomright{a}}\\ 
\only<2>{\marktopleft{b}}10 & 87 & 112 & 1.6\only<2>{\markbottomright{b}}\\ 
20 & 92 & 115 & 1.6 \\ 
30 & 87 & 117 & 1.6 \\ 
40 & 81 & 121 & 1.6 \\ 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}%

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot, but the tikzset you offered above affected my other tikzpictures, including my custom tikz bullet for the itemize environment. The bullets now appears south west of their corresponding items. Can you please suggest how to fix this?

Comment: @user8420488483439 Can you show a MWE that demonstrates the problem?