# Beamer's show notes only option and tikz markings

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

I followed the example provided in [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/367574/an-issue-with-hf-tikz-and-xcolor) to generate a table with annotations marking its contents, and it works as expected. However, when I added the beamer's command `\setbeameroption{show only notes}` to show the speaker's notes, the annotations did not show correctly (or at least the second one).

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[xcolor={table,dvipsnames}]{beamer}

\usetheme{Copenhagen}

% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/315248/36296
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,shapes,arrows,fit,tikzmark}

% Some options common to all the nodes and paths
\tikzset{   
    every picture/.style={remember picture,baseline},
    every node/.style={anchor=base,align=center,outer sep=1.5pt},
    every path/.style={thick},
}

\newcommand\marktopleft[1]{%
    \tikz[overlay,remember picture] 
    \node (marker-#1-a) at (.1em,.3em) {};%
}
\newcommand\markbottomright[1]{%
    \tikz[overlay,remember picture] 
    \node (marker-#1-b) at (.1em,.3em) {};%
    \tikz[overlay,remember picture,inner sep=1pt]
    \node[draw=red,rounded corners,fit=(marker-#1-a.north west) (marker-#1-b.south east)] {};%
}

\setbeameroption{show only notes}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{}

\begin{table}
\centering 
\rowcolors{2}{gray!20}{white}
\begin{tabular}{lccc}
A & B & C & D \\ 
00 & 100\% & 100\% & 0\% \\ 
\only<1>{\marktopleft{a}}05 & 58 & 181 & 50\only<1>{\markbottomright{a}}\\ 
\only<2>{\marktopleft{b}}10 & 87 & 112 & 1.6\only<2>{\markbottomright{b}}\\ 
20 & 92 & 115 & 1.6 \\ 
30 & 87 & 117 & 1.6 \\ 
40 & 81 & 121 & 1.6 \\ 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}%

\note<1>{The first note.}
\note<2>{The second note.}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The annotation appearing with the second note is not correct. By the way, I did compile two times, but this did not help.

Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: This is not subjected to tabular. Essentially the snapshot on the upper right corner will confuses Ti*k*Z. One cannot expect that `remember picture` will be compatible with heavy box-tricks.

Comment: @Symbol1: So in your opinion, is it `remember picture` that is causing this inconsistency between slide view and note view? Is it possible to make both views consistent? If so, would you please post a MWE?

Comment: tl;dr: I cannot make it work. The fact that `show notes` and `show only notes` give different results just blew my mind. Not to mention the fact that if you have more than four notes, the red rectangles start dancing.

Answer (score 2):

This is not really an answer, but is a bit long for a comment.

Beamer's `show only notes` option includes the command `\nofiles`.  This means that, in particular, the `aux` file is not generated.  TikZ's `remember picture` mechanism depends on writing coordinates to the aux file to be read back in on the next run.  The reason for disabling this in `show only notes` is probably so that generating just the notes doesn't mess with labels and so forth in the main presentation, and so that such things in the mini-version reflect those in the actual presentation.

But this messes up TikZ's `remember picture` syntax.  As stated above, no aux file is generated when `show only notes` is given.  Even with the aux file from the main presentation, the connection between the individual tikz pictures and the information in the aux file is almost certainly broken as the number of tikz pictures will be different (and tikz identifies pictures by a simple count).

So I doubt an easy solution exists, and solving it might just break more things than it fixes.